# ERROR ITMS-90023: “Missing required icon file” Xcode 9

Tags: ios11, xcode9

I'm trying to upload my App to Apple Store but it's doing this error

[image]

All of my icons it's all ok. I already clean project and added icon name in info.plist.

Anyone help me, please!

Comment: Try to export an IPA through **Organizer -> Archives -> Export** and upload the IPA through Application Loader.

Comment: Application Loader are give me a error with login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to your Assets.xcassets, click the + in bottom left -> App Icons & Launch Images -> New iOS App Icon.
2. Add the correct icon sizes in their place just like normal.

Remember to change your 'App Icons and Launch Images'  (in the General Settings) to the new icon set you just created.